# Finding if an array is an arithmetic sequence

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

so my requirements are

- REQUIRES: n >= 1.  Elements a[0] ... a[n-1] exist.
- PROMISES

  - The return value is 1 if n == 1.
  - If n > 1, the return value is 1 if a[0] ... a[n-1] form
    an arithmetic sequence.
- PROMISES
  Otherwise, the return value is 0.

my function so far is

```
int is_arith_seq(const int *a, int n)
{
    assert(n >= 1);

    if (n == 1)
    return 1;

    int dif = a[0],i;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        dif = a[i]-a[i+1];
        if(dif=)


    }
}
```

the edit for the loop that only runs once, which someone in the comments pointed out

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    currentdif = a[i+1]-a[i];
    if(initaldif!=currentdif)
        return 0;
}
        return 1;
```

as you can see it is not complete,as I am completely stuck now, what can I do to complete it?

Comment: How would you do this manually?  i.e. if I gave you {1, 4, 7, 10, 13} how would you know it's an arithmetic sequence?

Comment: Keep in mind the definition of an arithmetic sequence- for each two consecutive elements a[i+1] and a[i], a[i+1]-a[i] is some constant d.
you can easily infer what this constant should be from the first two elements, and then check that it holds with all other elements.

Comment: Watch out for *off-by-one* errors: your code accesses `a[n]` (when calculating `dif` on the last time through the loop) which does not exist.

Comment: You have to check all the elements, you are returning before completing the check. The code should be while (current_diff == first_diff) { continue checking }

Comment: Do not change your question significantly after answers had been given, as this might render the answers un-understandable. Add news as updates/additions. I therefore rolled back your last edit.

Comment: Once you find out the array is not an arithmetic sequence (when `initialdif != currentdif`) no matter how many more elements the array has it will never become an arithmetic sequence. You can `return 0` right then and only keep checking the rest of the elements when the portion you have checked so far is an arithmetic sequence

Comment: i have edited it once again, still no luck

Comment: Again: pay attention to [off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)! You are accessing `a[n]` inside the loop.

Comment: man ive edited it so many times I dont see the problem. could you please just tell me.thanks

Comment: "*could you please just tell me*" why, this is your job, or isn't this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use two variables: `firstdif` and `currentdif`

```
firstdif = a[1] - a[0];
for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    currentdif = a[i] - a[i - 1];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i edited my code, I am getting it right for some test samples and wrong for some.

Comment: After the code edit: the code now only goes through the loop once. It either returns `0` or `1` the first time through the loop and never executes the loop again

Comment: Don't return from the function until either you determine the array is not an aithmetic sequence (when `currentdif != firstdif`) or you went through all the differences.

Comment: the code i updated goes through all the elements doesnt it? currentdif goes through each element because i keeps on incrementing

Comment: whether the condition you test inside the loop is true or false, your code returns and exits the function. You have a `return` both in the `if` and `else` parts

Comment: i have edited my code, but still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you just need two variables.
Difference between first two terms : diff0
Difference between any other consecutive two terms (a[i] and a[j]) : current_diff

Now, iterate array until current_diff == diff0.
If you visit all elements then array represent arithmetic series
else it does not.

Comment: i have edited my loop, but it does not iterate properly. how would i iterate properly?

Comment: what do you mean it does not iterate properly ?

Comment: also you are accessing a[n] ...when i become n-1

Comment: what edit should i make to my program, to make it run smoothly

Comment: Your edited code is fine ..you initialize i with 3 and go till i < n. CurrentDiff =a[i] - a[i-1] . initialDiff is difference between first two elements